# update duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow for Service Bus Topic via ARM Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-topics

How do I update duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow value for Service Bus Topic via ARM Template?

Here is my ARM Template that sets duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow to 1 minute however the deployment is failing:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusName'), '/', parameters('topicName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
            "properties": {
                "path": "[parameters('topicName')]",
                "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
                "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P14D",
                "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "P01M"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To set `duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow` to 1 minute, you need to specify it with `PT1M` instead of `P01M`.

Just use the template below, it works fine on my side.

```
"resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusName'), '/', parameters('topicName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
            "properties": {
                "path": "[parameters('topicName')]",
                "requiresDuplicateDetection": true,
                "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P14D",
                "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "PT1M"
            }
        }
    ]
```

[image]

[image]